# Showing product Thumbnail for link in WhatsApp || og:image meta-tag doesn't work in shopify

Tags: shopify, seo, whatsapp, meta-tags, shopify-app

```
  {%- if template_base == 'product' -%}
    <meta property="og:price:amount" content="{{ product.price | money_without_currency | strip_html }}">
    <meta property="og:price:currency" content="{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}">
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if page_image -%}
    <meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ page_image | img_url: '250x250' }}">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ page_image | img_url: '250x250' }}">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ page_image.width }}">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ page_image.height }}">
  {%- endif -%}
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="{{ settings.social_twitter_link | split: 'twitter.com/' | last | prepend: '@' }}">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ og_title }}">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ og_description | strip_html }}">
```

I changed img size 250x250 but still not showing on the whatsapp